# How to reverse a list without modifying the original list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to use the reverse() method in the following way:

```
>>> L=[1,2,3]
>>> R=L
>>> L.reverse()
>>> L
[3, 2, 1]
>>> R
[3, 2, 1]
```

Why does it reverse R as well?
How do I keep the original list and create a reversed on?

Thanks!

Comment: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to make a copy of your list

```
L=[1,2,3]
# R=L
R = L[:]
L.reverse()
```

or more directly (reversing using slice notation):

```
R = L[::-1]
```

if you just write `R = L` then `R` is just a new reference on the same list `L`.

if you also need to copy the elements in your list, use [`copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy); `R = L[:]` only produces a shallow copy (which is fine in your case where there are only `int`s in the list).

Comment: Mind you, the simplest solution is to combine the shallow copy slice with reversal, to get the canonical reversing slice: `R = L[::-1]`

Answer (score 1):

To avoid reversing `R`, you need a copy of `L`

To make a copy, change

```
R=L    <---- this is not copying L in to R
```

to

```
R= L[:]    <---- this will create a copy of L in to R
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> L=[1,2,3]
>>> R=list(reversed(L))
>>> R
[3, 2, 1]
>>> L
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do

```
R = L[:]
```

Read about copying and deep copying to understand why this is happening. In short, it is because when you do `R = L`, both point to the "same" list in memory so reversing one will reverse the other.

Alternately you can use [deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy)

Answer (score 0):

The operation

```
R=L
```

means that the variable R stores whatever L is storing i.e R references to whatever value L is refering. Now, when you reverse L, it means the list L is refering to is reversed.As R is also refereing same address, you are seeing R as reversed.

Answer (score 0):

You have been bitten by the fact that Python assigns references, not copies.

Python uses reference exclusively in order to prevent unneeded copies. It uses references also when passing function arguments, and even with default function arguments. It only makes a copy when you explicitly tell it to, e.g. by doing

```
L = list(R)
```

or

```
from copy import copy
L = copy(R)
```

The difference between the two is that `list(R)` always returns a list, where `copy` returns an object of the same type as the original. Also, `copy` does not work with iterators, but `list` does.

Note that these are 'shallow' copies. If the list contains objects, the new list contains references to the same objects. For 'deep' copies, it has the function `deepcopy` in the module `copy`.

```
from copy import deepcopy
L = deepcopy(R)
```

But in practise there is rarely a need to make explicit copies. Python provides e.g. the `reversed` built-in that can be used to iterate through the list.

```
for l in reversed(L):
    # do stuff
```

It returns an iterator, so it is efficient. No need to duplicate the list. Other cases where a copy might be needed can be handled by e.g. generator functions.  A valid case for a copy might be when pasing data past thread boundaries.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but I get:  
>>> L=[1,2,3]
>>> R=reversed(L)
>>> R
<list_reverseiterator object at 0x02DB0E10>   
>> What do I do wrong?

Comment: The result of `reversed` is not for storing in a variable, but for use in a for loop (or list comprehension). No need to store duplicate data... I have updated my answer.

Comment: @Hana you need `R=list(reversed(L))`